# Load ReactJS component on the same page overwriting other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a Home Component that contains other components. One of the components is a multi-step sign-up form that has three steps - 1. Choose Plan, 2. Account Details and 3. Thank you page. The Home component displays the first step of the multi-step Sign-up form which is the Choose Plan component.

Upon clicking the plan, I want the Account component to open on the same page overwriting the Home component instead of replacing the current component. At the same time, I want the props to pass on to the child components.

Home Component containing the SignUpForm

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Video/>
        <Featured/>
        <SignUpForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Multi-step sign-up form -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Plan from "./Plan";
import Account from "./Account";
import ThankYou from "./ThankYou";

export default class SignUpForm extends Component {
  state = {
    step: 1,
    account_type: "",
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  };

  // Proceed to next step
  nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step + 1
    });
    console.log(this.state.step);
  };

  // Go back to previous step
  prevStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 1
    });
  };

  // Handle fields change
  handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    const {
      account_type,
      price,
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      password,
      token
    } = this.state;
    const values = {
      account_type,
      price,
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      password,
      token
    };

    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <Plan
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <Account
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            prevStep={this.prevStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        );
      case 3:
       return <ThankYou />;

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a grandchild of the `Home` component to override the home component? You simply can't do that this way.

If the reason you want to override, is that you don't want to show the `Video` and `Featured` component simply move up the 'step' logic to the `Home` component. You could then return like this:

```
switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <Video />
          <Featured />
          <Plan
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <Account
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            prevStep={this.prevStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        );
      case 3:
       return (
        <Video>
        <Featured />
        <ThankYou />
       );

    }
```

If you really want to replace the Home component move all the logic up one more component, a High Order Component.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  \\all your logic and inside the render function:
  switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <Home {...props}/>
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <Account
            {...props}
          />
        );
      case 3:
       return (
         <Home {...props}/>
       );

    }
  }
```

Just remember that when moving up logic, state becomes props in the lower components and you need to pass down the state from the logic in the higher component down as props.

Comment: Thanks! This helped. I'll work my way using this logic

Answer (score 0):

I am not super clear on if you want this to stay at the top of the screen?

```
<Video/>
<Featured/>
```

If you are using something like React-Navigation for your app you can pass params this way and rather than using a switch statement, use Navigation.navigate to get to your specific screen of choice.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html